# Why should a Bash Script crash/exit when running mysqladmin with Unix Socket Auth off?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Why should a Bash Script crash/exit when running mysqladmin with Unix Socket Auth off?

I need to TRAP "mysqladmin status" to ensure the script does not exit.
I'm using 10.6 on Ubuntu 22.04.
Is there a better way of testing for Unix Socket Auth off?

```
# cat test-mariadb.sh 
#!/bin/bash

test_status1() {
    mysqladmin status >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
    echo "$?"
}

test_status2() {
    mysqladmin -uroot -psecret status >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
    echo "$?"
}

echo "Testing Mariadb for Unix Socket Auth off ..."

##Without TRAP this script crashes if Unix Socket Auth is OFF
RET="$(trap test_status1 EXIT)"
echo "TRAP RETURN1 is: <$RET>"

RET="$(trap test_status2 EXIT)"
echo "TRAP RETURN2 is: <$RET>"

exit 0


cat /etc/my.cnf
[mariadb]
unix_socket=OFF
```

Comment: just curious, why are you testing this? Why is it important to disable?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error is one way

```
e=$(mariadb -u root --default-auth=unix_socket 2>&1)
if [ "e" = "ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin 'unix_socket' is not loaded" ]; then
   # not loaded
fi
```

Though password authentication on the root user in most scenarios is weaker than [unix_socket authentication](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/#security).

Answer (score 0):

Bash, as well as other Unix shells, should not crash nor exit when invocation of a external utility, such as `mysqladmin`, causes an error, unless `set -e` is in effect or an ERR trap is defined that causes it to exit.

A command that sets a trap on exit, such as `trap action EXIT`, will cause the command `action` to be execute when the shell (or subshell) in which the trap has ben set exits, so the traps in your scripts do not work how you think they do.

This modified version of test-mariadb.sh should be equivalent to the one you included in your question.

```
#!/bin/bash

test_status1() {
    mysqladmin status >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
}

test_status2() {
    mysqladmin -uroot -psecret status >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
}

echo "Testing Mariadb for Unix Socket Auth off ..."

test_status1
echo "TRAP RETURN1 is: $_"

test_status2
echo "TRAP RETURN2 is: $_"
```